# error establishing a database connection

Tags: database, errors

I know this question is asked like a million times, but I can't find an answer for my problem.

This problem is happening in a user of my server (my father's blog actually), and as he told me: "Just finished a post and was editing the text and the image layout when the site froze. Then tried when a different opened tab but couldn't do anything either".

Since then, the famous "error establishing a database connection" has been there.

This is the information I can give:

- The wp-config file is correct (it was working before and has not been changed. Also, I checked it)
- The MySQL server is working fine, and I can connect to the database with a small PHP script, and select the database
- The tables of the database need no repair (I also run the mysqlrepair tool)
- There's no `.maintenance` file

Actually, in the functions.php:is_blog_installed() it couldn't find the siteurl option and as it's not repairing, the function returns false...

Any idea why or how to recover the blog?

Comment: It's possible there is some issue with the network connection between your database server and your wordpress server. Have you verified connectivity has not been blocked between those two devices?

Comment: As I said, there's no problem with the server. I tested it with a small script. And everything is in localhost, so no communication problem...

Comment: Are you able to export the database and import to a newly created database and then change the db credentials in wp-config.php to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still facing the issue? I might be able to help you out.

Here are some more reasons why it might be happening:

- A corrupted database – Bad plugins, addons, themes and data-transfer interruptions might leave your database short of tables or completely corrupted at worst.
- Corrupted WordPress files

Found this on: http://www.wpkube.com/how-to-fix-error-establishing-database-connection-in-wordpress/

Comment: forgot to comment here. Actually, it seemed a bad plugin or something (weird because it was working), so I just disabled some plugins from console and reinstalled wordpress... and now is working...